# WPF component InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, wpf

I have trouble with getting the text value of WPF TextBox.

[image: img]

There are many same exception list(InvalidOperationException) on textbox.
Why does these exception occur?   To remove these exceptions , what should I do?

These are code snippets.

```
public partial class MainPage : Page, 
                                Autodesk.Revit.UI.IDockablePaneProvider    
{
       ...
     private static BackgroundWorker workerTimers = new BackgroundWorker();

}

public sync void LoadPage()
{
       ...
     workerTimers.DoWork += workerTimers_DoWork;
       ...
}

async void workerTimers_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
       ...
    SearchText = UserSearchTextBox.Text;
       ...
}
```

Comment: SearchText is string, and asign value of UserSearchTextBox.Text ? need to see first line from try

Comment: Thanks for your reply.   SearchText is string and assign value is UserSearchTextBox.Text.

Comment: Please provide code snippets and not screenshots.

Comment: I have added code snippets.  Hope this to help you.   Thanks.

Comment: look fine, just try to change DoWorkEventArgs with RoutedEventArg e, and be sure your function is public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't utilize WPF controls from a background thread. You need to access them from the main UI thread. Use the Dispatcher property on the control:

```
UserSearchTextBox.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => SearchText = UserSearchTextBox.Text);
```

Are you expecting the data to change while the background thread is running? If not, grab it before you start the background thread.